# Связь один к одному внутри одной таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, kohana, orm

Есть таблица категорий. Категории могут быть вложенными, поэтому у каждой категории есть родительская категория. Вопрос: как установить связь внутри модели? Вообще возможно ли такое?

```
Categories
--------------
id
title
parent_id
```

Comment: Я думаю этот топик должен помочь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390767/kohana-3-3-orm-how-to-find-all-ancestors-in-a-tree-self-referencing-table

Comment: У меня есть чистый код без использования kohana, показать?

Comment: SiZE, спасибо, то что надо :)
Андрей, не надо, интересовал именно orm kohana-ы

Answer (score 1):

Мне знакомы три способа организации подобной древовидной структуры:

- [**Adjacency list**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) - классический пример с parent_id и рекурсивным обходом
- [**Nested set**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) - использование некоторого диапазона на каждом из подуровней
- **Matherialized Path** - плоское представление всего пути к элементу от root-а, а-ля раздел "содержание" любой книги (1.1.2)

На практике использую первый подход (Adjacency list) для категорий, ибо может возникнуть сценарий, при котором необходимо некую подкатегорию перенести из одной категории в другую. Последний (Matherialized Path) для древовидный комментариев. Оба подхода реализую на уровне бизнес-логики проекта.

Если используется PostgreSQL, то с помощью логики рекурсивных запросов можно реализовать Adjacency list подход ([пример реализации](https://youtu.be/qMpF3eMq_Kc?t=25m53s)). Не думаю, что какая-нибудь ORM поддерживает данную специфику, а потому: плоский запрос с использование Query Builder-а/DBAL фреймворка вам в помощь.

Дополнительно можете почитать [официальную документацию MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/), где реализация всех этих подходов описана.

[Видео лекции по БД представителя mail.ru](https://youtu.be/lRz21ZfvLnM?t=2h11m48s), где эти подходы затрагиваются.

Связь 1:M при Adjacency list с использованием первичного и внешнего ключей в рамках одной таблицы можно и нужно для поддержки ссылочной целостности.

**P.S.** Здесь всё-таки связь 1:M, ибо у категории может быть множество подкатегорий.