# Как реализовать партнерскую программу на сайте в восемь уровней вложенности с помощью php и MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, алгоритм

Хочу реализовать партнерскую программу на сайте в восемь уровней вложенности но не знаю как можно такое реализовать с помощью php и MySQL. Принцип работы такой: если пользователь A привел пользователя B то А становится его рефералом и его уровень 1, а если пользователь B привел пользователя С то B становится его рефералом и его уровень 2 для пользователя А и 1 для пользователя Б, но если А приведет D то А становится его рефералом и его уровень 1 и так до восьмого уровня вложенности пользователей. Надеюсь суть поняли.

Но потом мне нужна ка-кто их выводить из БД и для каждого пользователя отображать их уровент вложенности на пример:

  если пользователь А то:
- B - 1 уровень
- D - 1 уровень
- С - 2 уровень

  а если пользователь B то:
- C - 1 уровень

[image: Вот нашел пример картинки для болея удобного понимания]

Comment: Да все просто, по сути. Достаточно в интернете посмотреть как реализовываются древовидные меню на сайтах и по аналогии сделать, только применить к рефералам. Это полный равнозначный аналог

Comment: Посмотрите [мой ранее данный ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422742/10551). В условиях неопределённого количества участников на любом из уровней, стоит присмотреться к Adjacency list или Matherialized Path.

Answer (score 6):

Есть несколько популярных методов представления древовидных данных в БД:

- Adjacency List,
- Materialized Paths,
- Nested Sets.

У каждого есть свои плюсы и минусы. Выбор за вами, в зависимости от вашей конкретной специфики.
Если данные будут добавляться нечасто, а вычисление "уровня" это типичный кейс, то я бы рекомендовал `Nested Sets`. См. слайдшоу с кратким описанием ключевых моментов каждой из техник:
[image]
http://www.slideshare.net/quipo/trees-in-the-database-advanced-data-structures
(На стр. 66 как раз пример вычисления уровня для всех записей NS одним SQL-запросом.)

```
-- Партнеры, организованные в структуру Nested Sets
CREATE TABLE partners (
  user_id INT(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  lft INT(10) NOT NULL,
  rgt INT(10) NOT NULL
);
-- Вычисление уровня для записи :id (уровни нумеруются с 1)
SELECT p2.user_id, COUNT(p1.user_id) AS lvl
FROM partners AS p1 JOIN
     partners AS p2 ON p2.lft BETWEEN p1.lft AND p1.rgt
WHERE p2.user_id = :id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f76f/9 - уровень для конкретной записи
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f76f/10 - уровни для всех записей

Comment: Партнерская сеть вещь постоянно меняющаяся. В таких условиях вариант в `Nested Sets` ИМХО будет крайне неудобен. Если взять за основу рисунок из Вашего ответа - то какие действия придется сделать, чтобы у `C` появился еще один реферал `G` и какие у него будут идентификаторы?

Comment: Я дал ссылку, где все базовые операции расписаны. И даже обрисован метод сокращения издержек. Алсо, я сделал оговорку: NS выгоден тогда, когда данные добавляются нечасто. Можно конечно вообразить этакий партнерский facebook, но лучше прикинуть реальные цифры — как часто будут добавляться новые записи: раз в день, в час или в секунду. Лично я не ничего не навязываю, но призываю к трезвой оценке.

Answer (score 1):

Три столбца:

1. Id, int, primaryKey
2. ParentId, int (null если сам пришёл)
3. ChildIds, varchar. Массив id рефералов, разделённых запятой.

Добавлять реферала записью

```
ChildIds=ChildIds.",".Id;
```

Где Id - это ид нового юзера.

Узнать всех рефералов просто перебрав Id из ChildIds

Проследить с любого уровня до верху - запрашивать ParentId пока он не null.

P.S. Это может быть велосипед и не нормальная форма БД, но работать будет же.

Answer (score -1):

если нужно только количетство тогда пример [@artoodetoo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459435/182317) отличный.

но если нужно создать эту системы и также отображать своих пользователей, нужно немного развить таблицу.

Есть 2 метода разбиение уровни. 
* У каждого реферала по 2 пользователя 
* У каждого реферала по несколько пользователей

если **вариант 1й** тогда таблица имеет вид

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id INT(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  referrer_id INT(10),  
  referrer_side char(1) DEFAULT 'N',  
  left_user_id INT(10) NOT NULL,
  left_count INT(10) NOT NULL,
  right_user_id INT(10) NOT NULL,
  right__count INT(10) NOT NULl,
  is_active char(1) DEFAULT 'A'
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES
  (1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 'A'),
  (2, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 'A');
```

тут легче передвигатся между уровнями и пользовательями

**user_id** - сам пользователь

**referrer_id** - его реферал, если нету 0

**referrer_side** - с какой стороны стоит пользовател у реферала

**left_user_id** - пользователь по левой стороне

**left_count** - число пользователей в левой части

**right_user_id** - пользователь по правой стороне

**right__count** - число пользователей в правой части

**is_active** - пользователь Активный(A) или Удалень (D)

При добавлении нового пользователья, вам нужно пройтись по `referrer_id` и увеличить их количество пользователей (до 7 уровней). При удалении тоже самое. Только при удалении нужно вам подумать что делать и его пользовательями.

Само дерево можно составить с циклами до 8.

**если 2й вариант**

тут число пользователей у реферала не ограничено, придется создать допольнительно таблицу для всязок. Но думаю у Вас задача не такая

Думаю поможет.

Comment: Я не PHP разработчик (_не из тех, кто минусует_), но всё же... Не могли бы вы проаргументировать написанное?

Comment: я PHP разработчик и его не минусую. Но и аргументы дам.

Comment: @LEQADA удалил старое, добавил новый вариант

Comment: Да @Artoodetoo, как раз мне нужен второй вариан у меня число пользоавателей не ограничено