# Php Обратная иерархия категорий

Tags: php, mysql

Есть массив категорий, имеющих поля `id`, `parrent_id`, `url`, где `parrent_id` - `id` родителя

```
$cats = array();
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id,parrent_id,url FROM table");
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
      $cats[] = $row;
}
```

Например
Раздел 1
Раздел 1.1
Раздел 1.2
Раздел 1.2.1
Раздел 1.3
Раздел 2
Раздел 2.1
Раздел 3
Раздел 3.1
Раздел 3.2
Раздел 3.3

Как, зная `id` категории `Раздел 1.2.1` массива `$cats`, вывести на `php` обратный массив родительских категорий содержащий урлы

```
Array
(
[0] => 'урл_раздела_1.2.1'
[1] => 'урл_раздела_1.2'
[2] => 'урл_раздела_1'
)
```

Comment: Посмотрите мой ранее [данный ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422742/10551). В нём я указал, как с помощью БД организовать древовидную структуру.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задача стандартная и у нее много решений.

Например, если вы 100% уверены, что у в Вашем дереве категорий будет максимум три уровня, то, при правильно расставленных индексах, можно себе позволить и три запроса в базу сделать. Это не сильно напряжет систему.

Создать `do { ... } while()` петлю, которая будет запрашивать в базе каждую запись, перескакивая с одного `parrent_id` на следующий и заполняя массив урлов.

---

Однако лучше всего иметь какой-то универсальный код, который будет работать для неограниченного кол-ва категорий.

Могу предложить такой вариант:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id,parrent_id,url FROM table");
$cats = Array(); // полный набор категорий, оформленный как ассоциативный массив, где ключ - `id`
$parentTree = array(); // результат
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
      $cats[$row["id"]] = $row;
}

// предположим надо пройти по дереву категорий вверх, начиная с `id=151`;
$catID = 151; 
do {
    $parentTree[] = $cats[$catID]["url"]; // заносим `url` в результирующий массив
    $catID = $cats[$catID]["parrent_id"]; // далее будем искать по новому `parrent_id`
} while(array_key_exists($catID, $cats)); // крутимся до тех пор, пока `parrent_id` известен. Т.е. на 0 (верхний уровень) петля завершится

var_dump($parentTree);
```

В результате получаем массив с `url` вверх по лестнице.

Главный плюс тут вижу в том, что в БД производится один запрос. Все остальное происходит на уровне `php`, что всегда лучше.
Имея такие массивы можно двигаться также по дереву вниз. Только тут сложнее, потому что могут быть (и будут) категории с несколькими подкатегориями. Т.е. удобней делать встроенные массивы.

Comment: `Главный плюс тут вижу в том, что в БД производится один запрос.` Вы не правы. [Почитайте](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422742/10551). В PostgreSQL можно рекурсивным запросом всё это сделать.

Comment: @romeo согласен, однаков в тэгах вопроса `mysql` - соответственно и ответ с ним

Comment: Да нет, всё верно. Когда-то я сам использовал подобную логику с MySQL.

Comment: Спасибо, все доходчиво и понятно.